# Is it possible to link parameters?

Tags: scripting, compositing-nodes

I have several File Output nodes in the compositor that point to the same directory. I would like to set the path only in one of them and have the others read that value by setting an expression or token or whatever you want to call it. Is that possible?

Comment: But, why you don't use one output node for all images?

Comment: Because sometimes I just want to rerender a certain renderlayerlayer and then I can just mute the other outputs.